# In tasleem, should we pause between salam to the right and left?

Tags: salat

When ending the salah with the tasleem are you meant to pause in between, some people seem to give one salam to the right and look straight ahead for a moment then give the second salam to the left, others just give each salam one after the other.

Answer (score 3):

First, this is a branch of *al-ikhtilāf as-sā'igh*, i.e., the scholarly opinions are deduced but are not based on a direct verse in the Qur'an or a hadith that can be quoted. This also means that whichever school you follow will be accepted, Allah willing.

#### Hanafi

I do not know if there is any view specific to the Hanafi school on how to perform *taslīm* at the end of the prayers.

#### Maliki and Shafi'i

Both Maliki and Shaf'i' schools have a slight pause in between the two *taslīms* as one starts the *taslīm* facing *al-Qiblah* and ends the *taslīm* as one completes turning around. Then one pauses slightly until one returns to facing *al-Qiblah*, then one starts the *taslīm* to the left. In *At-Tahthīb* (Shafi'i) by [Al-Baghawi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Baghawi):

> والسُّنَّة أن يبتدئ السلام مستقبل القِبلة، ويتمه ملتفتاً، فحيث يكون انقضاء سلامه مع تمام الالتفات، ففي التسليمة الأولى يلتفت عن يمينه حتى يرى من على يمينه خدَّه الأيمن، وفي التسليمة الثانية يلتفت عن يساره حتى يرى من على يساره خدَّه الأيسر.
>
> <sub>*— **NOTE**: My own translation, so treat with care:*</sub>
>
> The sunnah is to start *as-Salām* facing *al-Qiblah* and to finish it while turned around so that it [*taslīm*] ends as one ends turning around. In the first *taslīm*, one turns around until those on one's right can see one's right cheek. In the second *taslīm*, one turns around until those on one's left can see one's left cheek.
>
> <sub>— [*At-Tahthīb*, Vol. 2, pp. 133](https://al-maktaba.org/book/33190/630#p6)</sub>

The Maliki school has the same view as per [Hāshiyat Al-'Adawi, Vol. 1, pp. 280](https://al-maktaba.org/book/21597/278) by ['Alia as-Sa'īdi al-'Adawi](https://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%B9%D9%84%D9%8A_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B5%D8%B9%D9%8A%D8%AF%D9%8A_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B9%D8%AF%D9%88%D9%8A).

#### Hanbali

In the Hanbali school, there is also a slight pause in between both *taslīms* as the view is to start saying *as-salāmu 'alaikum* while facing *al-Qiblah* and to continue without pausing to turn one's head while saying *wa rahmatu Allah*. There will be then a slight pause until one returns one head to face *al-Qiblah* before starting the second *taslīm*. In *Al-Insāf* by ['Alā' ad-Dīn al-Mardāwi](https://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%B9%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%A1_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AF%D9%8A%D9%86_%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%B1%D8%AF%D8%A7%D9%88%D9%8A):

> يستقبل القبلة بالسلام عليكم ويلتفت بالرحمة
>
> <sub>*— **NOTE**: My own translation, so treat with care:*</sub>
>
> Starts by facing *al-Qiblah* with *as-salāmu 'alaikum* then turns with *ar-rahmah*
>
> <sub>— [*Al-Insāf*, Vol. 4, pp. 562](https://al-maktaba.org/book/33212/1519)</sub>

Comment: The mainline in the Maliki school is a single tasleem for Imam and a person praying alone! [Tasleem at the end of salat - Maliki school](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2621/tasleem-at-the-end-of-salat-maliki-school)

Comment: @Medi1Saif, understood, but this is a different topic as to which taslīm is a corner (Hanafi: none, Malika: one, Shafi'i: two, Hanbali: either one a what Ibn Qudama said or two as what others said). However, there is no prohibition (see this [fatwa](https://islamqa.info/en/105297)) and even some Maliki scholars consider the second taslīm mandatory. The number of taslīms is matter of _khilāf mu'tabar_, but the methodology is _khilāf sā'igh_. There is also how many taslīms are there as an _imām_ vs. as a _ma'mūm_.